# how to get start time and end time after resizing the events in calender and also its respective event name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id='wrap'>
    <div id='external-events'>
        <div id='external-events-listing'>
            <h4>Channel List</h4>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <ul id="daysEvent"></ul>
            <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

after dragging and dropping the events into the calender,
how to get start time and end time after resizing the events in calender and also its respective event name?
[Working demo and complete code here in js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/166uz7L1/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use eventResize
I have made a fiddle for this

https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/0g7k27na/18/

```
eventResize: function(event,jsEvent,ui,view) {
   console.log("event",event);
}
```

Comment: when i resize , i want that start and stop time in alert box

Comment: are you looking for the start and end date of the event after dragend

Comment: Please check again the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/0g7k27na/20/

Comment: Thanks but it shows GMT time zone right? how to convert to indian time

Comment: Can you please again its showing Indian standard time.

Comment: i need some button which gets me all events present in calender with its name and start & stop time , so that i can send it to backend to store in my database

Comment: Event : My Event 4 StartTime : Thu May 11 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) End Sat May 13 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: Event : a StartTime : Fri May 19 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) End Fri May 19 2017 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)                i am getting start time as end time and vice versa